# How to serve static file(index.html) and REST services with different context path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have already put hard effort to search but I could not find specific solution for following situation.

I have written ***user*** services using `@RequestMapping("user")` annotation. Endpoint url looks like

```
http://localhost:8080/user
```

But I want to expose services like

```
http://localhost:8080/myServices/user
```

I could do it by setting `server.context-path=/myServices` and also other services which are within same application should follow the same url pattern eg.

```
http://localhost:8080/myServices/OTHERENDPOINT
```

But also I want to access static content file `index.html` which is under `resources\static\` folder by this default url

```
http://localhost:8080
```

This is achievable if you use default `context-path(/)` but then you cannot use '/myServices' prefix in url.

I am using `Spring boot 1.3.3` **annotation based(no xml)** implementation. Is there any way to achieve this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your user service with `@RequestMapping("myServices/user")`.

Comment: Thank you. But I need to arrange all the services under `/myService` url not only `user` service. For example http://localhost:8080/myServices/OTHERSERVICE

Comment: The documentation says the context-path is the "Context path of the application" which includes the static content. I would add "/myService" to every RestController, but maybe someone knows a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set any webserver as frontend such as `Apache HTTPD`, you could serve static context straight from the Apache using a `mod_proxy` pointing to your static content.

Other approach is to publish the app as ROOT.war so it serves content just with the domain name `http://my.domain.org` and map al the services with `@RequestMapping("/services/user")` as you have already been told.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I do not use HTTPD and also that would not look good if you map all your services by writing `@RequestMapping("/myServices/user")`.

Comment: It does not look good means there is a good feature to configure it once and applied to all services, then it doesn't make sense to use it in that way

Comment: And which is this feature and why you cannot use this in this case?

Comment: setting the value of `spring.data.rest.base-path` in application.properties. But in my case `spring.data.rest.base-path` is being overwritten by `server.context-path` value.

Answer (score 0):

Into resources, add folder "static",  with all your static content, e.g

/yourapp

> /src/main/java/RestControllers
>
> /src/main/resources/yourapp.properties
>
> /src/main/resources/static
>
> > /views/home.html
> >
> > /other_resources

mvn spring-boot:run

http://localhost:/views/home.html

For REST 
`@RestController with @RequestMapping`